# SimpleModal Basic Modal Dialog: how to open unique windows within the same page?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, unique, simplemodal

I'm using the SimpleModal Basic Modal Dialog and am having trouble using it to open more than one unique window on a page (I don't need them to open at the same time or on top of one another).
I tried adding another class and calling out that class in my js file, but I'm not getting it.  Here is my [example page](http://adahliadesign.com/dev/contact-test.html), where I have the "i" icon (top-right) opening a contextual window --works exactly how I want it to.  I want the "share" icon (below the photo) to open another window to link to social sites.  I'm sure I'm missing something super elementary.  -Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I've put together some changes to your HTML and JavaScript, which
should solve the issue:

http://jsbin.com/inuna/edit

You are loading jQuery twice, so I suggest you remove one of them. If
you keep the version that is loading from the Google API, I'd suggest
using the 1.3.2 version instead of 1.2.6.

Hope that helps.

-Eric